# Temporal aspects for Linear Regression and other ML Methods

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression

Having completed an interesting course on Linear Regression on coursera, one aspect was never addressed that I am curious about in terms of best approach.

With reference to the classic house price prediction use case:

- It strikes me that house prices changes over time.
- What is the best approach therefore?
- Do we keep on updating the input replacing older house prices of yesteryear?
- Or do we add an extra feature for Date of Sale - include a temporal aspect as a feature? I mention this as it was never discussed, but at the same time it seems so obvious. Inclusion of such an attrbue means it may get a weight, etc.

I can think of a few things but am more interested in the expert opinion.

Comment: Does it become a time-series thing then?

Comment: Of course age vs height is not an issue for regression, but ...

Comment: no it cannot be a time series is my take

Comment: @whuber: You have a good view on most things, can you may be offer an insight here from the experts?

Comment: I should state multiple regression of course

Comment: age of house, same as age of people? yes and no, point is the recording of data, different scenarios and for houses not always available